# Weird syntax error in python 3.x logic

Tags: python, logic

For some reason there is a syntax error in the following logical evaluation:

`True is not None and not False is not not not None`

The error can be narrowed down to this statement:

`False is not not None`

Where the second `not` is highlighted.

This isn't important at all, but I was just interested in why this might be failing. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, not a duplicate strictly speaking, but the explanation is the same.

Comment: @BartoszKP: The *reason* for the syntax error is *exactly* the same. All comparison operators have the same precedence; it doesn't matter if you use `is`, `is not`, `==` or `!=` or `<` or `>` or `<=` or `>=`; the result is the same if you follow any of those by `not`.

Comment: You really should not be comparing booleans; leave that to `if` or `while` statements.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, that's what I meant by saying that "explanation is the same" ;) By "not a duplicate strictly" I meant on the other hand, that the question is a bit different :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another thing to remember is that `is`, `not` and `is not` are actually **three** separate operators. In other words, `is not` is not (no pun intended) a combination of `is` and `not`.

In the case of your example

```
False is not not None
```

Python tries to pass `False` and `not` to the `is not` operator. Since `not` is not a valid operand, a syntax error results.

Comment: (This ugliness is one of the reasons that `is` and `is not` shouldn't have been operators at all, but two builtin functions `is()` and `is_not()`.)

Answer (score 2):

`is not not` doesn't work. This is not a very bad thing, as it's never needed.

`is not` has the same operator precedence as `is`, which makes sense. `is` has a higher operator precedence than `not`, otherwise `x is not y` would mean `x is (not y)`, when it needs to mean `x is not (y)`.

But you can't figure out if `a is not not b` because you can't get the answer for `is not` before you do `not b`.